# Software crashing randomly and frequently. MS SQL error

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

So I just start this job at a small business and they have this software (lets call it "GDB") that crashes. The employees said this software did not have this issue three months ago but until recently, GDB either crashes and sometimes crashes during login. The software connects to a database MS SQL Server 2008. When the software crashes, text of the error appears. I was not the one who wrote the software so I don't know if it's a software or network issue. Please advise me on what to do, as my expertise on this is very limited.

This is the text that popped up when it crashes:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at GlobeDB.DataAccess.SqlDbObj.connect()
   at GlobeDB.DbAccessObjects.DbClientOrderObj.CheckForOtherUsersByOrder(Int32 OrderID)
   at GlobeDB.AppEditForm.updateViewer(Int32 OrderID, Int32 UserID)
   at GlobeDB.AppEditForm.AppEditForm_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.RaiseFormClosingOnAppExit()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at GlobeDB.AppEditForm.btnAddFileInfo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton.ButtonElement_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButtonItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.DoClick(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentInputBehavior.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5472 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
GlobeDB
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.28
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.28
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/GlobeDB.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.UI
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Telerik.WinControls.UI.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Telerik.WinControls.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5476 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
TelerikCommon
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/TelerikCommon.DLL
----------------------------------------
leas4y_i
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.GridView
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Telerik.WinControls.GridView.DLL
----------------------------------------
Telerik.WinControls.RadDock
    Assembly Version: 2010.1.10.504
    Win32 Version: 2010.1.10.0504
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Telerik.WinControls.RadDock.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.1
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.1
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Web
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5474 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_64/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.21022.8
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.DLL
----------------------------------------
expression_host_000aa2e2d44e4c96a39ef6234b731946
    Assembly Version: 10.8.30729.1
    Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.1
    CodeBase: file:///S:/GlobeDB/GLOBEDBFILES/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

EDIT****
Alright guys I basically found the issue, but can't find a resolution. The software crashes because of a port scan from the server. The server is port scanning workstations on the network due to a possible rootkit. I have tried removing and etc but I can't find it. Here is a link from previous work trying to find the rootkit. http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/528037/rootkit-on-windows-server-2008-port-scanning-network/
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to fix their crappy software (GDB).  First thing I might try is disabling Named Pipes, as it often causes problems... then again, some software requires it, so that might not work, in which case, we're back to getting the person/company that made GDB to fix their code.

Answer (score 2):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

It sounds like you're saying this is an intermittent problem.  If so, check the network connectivity between the GDB software and the SQL Server, including:

1. Make sure SQL Server is running and accepts connections via the method GDB expects.
2. If there's a firewall on the SQL Server, make sure it's not blocking connections to SQL.  By default, SQL 2008 uses dynamic ports, so it's not as easy as opening 1433.  (Link:  [How to set a static port for SQL 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938).)
3. Make sure the machine(s) running GDB can connect to SQL Server.  Check basic connectivity, including things like network cards that are trying to die.

If that doesn't work, it's probably time to contact the developer/vendor, alas.

Comment: +1. This looks like neither sql level nor software level problem but something with the network (can be the server, just not like sql server crashes). Seen that years ago on a totally overloaded network.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the great advice. I would totally upvote this but I can't with my current status. I will go through all the steps respectively and hopefully I will be able to resolve this. Thanks!